# jQuery and Scroll.To stop working once I archive (zip) or duplicate the folder

Tags: jquery, archive

Ok. This is about obscure as it gets.

I've been working on a website for a client. I uploaded the folder to my website, and everything is up to snuff. I used Scroll.To for smooth scrolling down the page.

Now the sites done, and he asks for a zip. Sure thing, right? Not so much.

He comes back and says that the scrolling doesn't work. I double check my own copy, and it works fine. Then I open up the archive and it doesn't work!

So then I try to duplicate the folder as well to throw it into the dropbox, and sure enough it doesn't work either.

Here is the important code: http://pastie.org/895201

So to recap:
- jQuery (and ONLY jQuery) breaks when I
   -a. duplicate the folder on Mac OS X.
   -b. archive/zip the folder on Mac OS X.
- It DOES work when I duplicate folder on my server, via Transmit FTP.
- All of the files are within the folder- I get no errors according to Safari as far as broken links
- I am clearly going nuts!

Answer (score 0):

There are several potential points of failure. Doing these 3 should help you to track down or rule out some other parts.

What are app are you using to zip the folder? Have you tried another app? This will rule out compression.

What do you use to decompress it? It could be that as well?

What happens if you don't dropbox the file? Can you email it? What about SCP vs. FTP?

My guess is that it's some combination of the 3 causing your issue.

Comment: It has to be an os x problem. I just used Cyberduck SFTP and created an archive there, and it works OK as well. 

This is just nuts.